# Can't open display after reattach screen session

Tags: linux, ubuntu, display, gnu-screen

When I first start my `screen` session my X-display works. I.e., I can start X-apps like `xterm`, etc.

However, when I reattach my previous `screen` session, from a different X, the X-display no longer works. E.g., if I start `xterm`, I'll get:

```
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

However my X-display (of localhost:10.0) works just find if I quit/suspend the reattach `screen` session. I.e., it works outside of reattach `screen` session, but not inside.

How to make my X-display works inside of the reattach `screen` session as well?

Comment: Are you using SSH with X11 forwarding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before reattach screen session,

```
env | grep -E "SSH_|DISPLAY|XAUTHORITY" | sed -e "s/ .*//" > ~/.scrrc
```

(The extra `sed` is to remove the extra arguments from SSH_CLIENT and SSH_CONNECTION, as bash variable assignment cannot contain unescaped spaces. Thanks to
Velda & ruud who left comments for the correction.), Or, *actually*, simply this will do too:

```
env | grep -E "SSH_AUTH|DISPLAY|XAUTHORITY" > ~/.scrrc
```

After reattach, within each screen session,

```
source ~/.scrrc
```

Define them as alias to ease typing each time.

Comment: Better to do `env | grep -E "SSH_|DISPLAY|XAUTHORITY" | sed -e "s/\=\(.*\)$/=\"\1\"/" > ~/.scrrc`, because bash variable assignment cannot contain unescaped spaces.

Comment: To remove the extra arguments from SSH_CLIENT and SSH_CONNECTION (port number), use `env | grep -E "SSH_|DISPLAY|XAUTHORITY" | sed -e "s/ .*//" > ~/.srcrc`